# Custom JSON Formatting

Tags: formatting, prettier

I am not your complete package programmer / developer. Please go easy on me. In many cases its just a search term I am unfamiliar with.

I have this code:

```
           "CustomFields": [
            {"Name": "TextTest2","Content": ""},
            {
                "Name": "DealerNames",
                "Content": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "PricingProducts",
                "Content": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "Structure",
                "Content": ""
            },
```

That i would prefer written like this:

```
       "CustomFields": [
            {"Name": "TextTest2","Content": ""},
            {"Name": "DealerNames","Content": ""},
            {"Name": "PricingProducts","Content": ""},
            {"Name": "Structure","Content": ""},
```

I am aware it is not the normal beautify / prettier structure but much of my inputs / outputs have thousands of key value pairs in JSON and all the additional spaces make the code hard to read.

I use VSCODE but any online formatter that has this option would be helpful.

If there is nothing just say so.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [FracturedJson](https://j-brooke.github.io/FracturedJson/).  It tries to make JSON readable by indenting, but keeping simple and short arrays/objects on a single line.  That link takes you to the browser-based formatter, but if it looks like what you're looking for, there's a [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=j-brooke.fracturedjsonvsc) extension too.  (Disclosure: I'm the author.  It's open-source under the MIT license.)

Here's what your sample data looks like, formatted with the default settings:

```
{
    "CustomFields": [
        { "Name": "TextTest2"      , "Content": "" },
        { "Name": "DealerNames"    , "Content": "" },
        { "Name": "PricingProducts", "Content": "" },
        { "Name": "Structure"      , "Content": "" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several online JSON formatters. For example [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

In this you can select compact option in JSON template. Using this your JSON text will be formatted to:

```
{"CustomFields":[{"Name":"TextTest2","Content":""},{"Name":"DealerNames","Content":""},{"Name":"PricingProducts","Content":""},{"Name":"Structure","Content":""}]}
```

However, I am not sure that getting all the elements on new line is possible in any formatter.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i fear maybe not. I might look into an extension in VSCode and see if there is a way to edit it. Again as a novice i might be speaking out of the wrong hole here. 

I have seen is "compact" as some call single line or no spacing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this JSON formatter and restructure your code - https://toolbox.land/json-formatter

or you can configure prettier to do the same as well https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).